# Как правильно присвоить указателю на указатель указатель

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    int i;
public:
    void modify() { i = 10; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foo x;
    Foo* p = nullptr;
    Foo** q = &p;     // Почему так правильно писать, 
    Foo** q = p;      // а так не правильно.

    *q = &x;

    return 0;
}
```

Как правильно рассуждать работая с подобными конструкциями. Правильней ли будет говорить не операция взятия адреса, а добавить уровень косвенности? Как в сл. коде?

```
std::string s = "HelloWorld!";     // Добавляем уровень косвенности
std::string* p1 = &s;
std::string** p2 = &p1;              
std::string*** p3 = &p2;
std::string**** p4 = &p3;
std::string***** p5 = &p4;        

std::string**** p6 = *p5;          // Снимаем уровень косвенности
std::string*** p7 = *p6;
std::string** p8 = *p7;
std::string* p9 = *p8;
std::string s2 = *p9;

std::string s3 = *****p5;
```

Comment: Потому что в первом случае вы присваиваете адрес указателя (не адрес, который он содержит, а адрес самого указателя), что и требуется. А во втором вы пытаетесь присвоить адрес объекта класса Foo (хоть он и ноль) переменной, которая должна содержать адрес указателя на Foo. Это разные типы, поэтому неправильно

Comment: Что такое `p`? Это указатель. А что такое `q`? Это тоже указатель. В чём же тогда между ними разница? Говорят, что `p` указывает **на** (`Foo`), а `q` указывает **на** (`Foo *`). То есть, эти два указателя указывают на объекты _разных_ типов: `p` указывает **на** (объект типа `Foo`), а `q` указывает **на** [объект типа указатель, который указывает **на** (объект типа `Foo`)]. Т.е. `p` и `q` - указатели разных типов. Нельзя без явного приведения типов присвоить указатель некоторого типа указателю другого типа. Вот почему код `Foo** q = p` некорректен.

Comment: Что такое `&p`? Это  операция взятия адреса. Что мы получим, взяв адрес объекта `p`? Мы получим указатель, который указывает **на** (`Foo *`), т.е. мы получим указатель, который указывает **на** [объект типа указатель, который указывает **на** (объект типа `Foo`)]. Т.е. тип `&p` - это `Foo **`, т.е. тип `&p` совпадает с типом `q`, поэтому код `Foo** q = &p` корректен.

Comment: Что происходит в выражении `*q`? Здесь мы обращаемся к значению, на которое указывает указатель `q`. А куда указывает `q`? `q` указывает на объект `p`. Т.е. `q` указывает **на** [объект типа указатель, который указывает **на** (объект типа `Foo`)]. Таким образом, разыменовывая `q`, мы работаем с объектом, на который указывает `q`, т.е. с объектом `p`. Так как `p` (т.е `*q`) - это указатель, который указывает **на** (`Foo`), то `p` (т.е `*q`) можно присвоить адрес объекта типа `Foo`, т.е адрес `x`.

Comment: "Как правильно рассуждать работая с подобными конструкциями?" Рассуждать о чем? `&p` имеет тип `Foo **` - вот и все рассуждения. Что именно вам в этом не ясно?

Comment: Я понимаю так, есть два адреса на стеке, p и q.  Сначала по адресу p пишем 0, потом по адресу q пишем адрес p, а затем по адресу p пишем адрес x, который тоже на стеке. Я правильно понимаю ? Если да то в ассемблерном коде все более менее понятно, а вот на C++ не могу понять.

Comment: Мне не понятно почему нельзя просто написать Foo** q = p; если p это просто адрес на стеке. Я так понимаю у меня с пониманием типизации проблемы?

Comment: `int i`. Переменная `i` предназначена для хранения целых чисел. Также у переменной `i` есть некоторый адрес, т.е., _условно говоря_, номер ячейки оперативной памяти, начиная с которой располагаются байты, в которых собственно и хранится значение переменной `i`. Узнать адрес, по которому расположена `i` можно с помощью операции взятия адреса : `&i`.

Comment: `int *pi`. Переменная `pi` предназначена для хранения адресов переменных типа `int`, т.е. значения переменной `pi` - это адреса. Как и у всякой переменной, у переменной `pi` также есть некоторый адрес, т.е., условно говоря, номер ячейки оперативной памяти, начиная с которой располагаются байты, в которых собственно и хранится значение переменной `pi`. Адрес переменной `i` **не равен** адресу переменной `pi` — это разные переменные, они хранятся в разных ячейках оперативной памяти и хранят значения **разных** типов.

Comment: " Сначала по адресу p пишем 0" — не совсем так. Выражение `Foo *p = nullptr;` означает, что переменной `p` присвоено нулевое указательное значение. То есть вы не по адресу `nullptr` записали ноль, а в те ячейки оперативной памяти, в которых расположена переменная `p`, записали значение `nullptr`.

Comment: И `q` и `p` оба указатели. Но `p` предназначен для хранения адресов объектов типа `Foo`, а `q` предназначен для хранения адресов объектов типа указатель на `Foo`. Указатели `p` и `q` указывают на объекты **разных** типов. "почему нельзя просто написать `Foo** q = p`" — если бы так можно было написать, то в переменной `q` стал бы храниться адрес объекта типа `Foo`. Но так как `q` хранит адрес указателя, то при разыменовании `q`, байты составляющие объект типа `Foo` стали бы интерпретироваться как указатель. А это нехорошо.

Comment: Посмотрите [пример](https://ideone.com/n02QoW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что p у вас указатель на класс, а q - указатель на указатель. Во втором случае вы пытаетесь присвоить указателю на указатель указатель на class, а в первом адрес указателя.