# Теряется указатель

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

```
// Алфавит
const char alphabet[] = { 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '@', '$', '!', '?', '*' };


// Проверка равенства строк
bool smp_local(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    return (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0);
}


// Создание дерева
struct tree* DB_Create() {
    struct tree* res = (new (struct tree));
    res->root = NULL;
    return res;
}


// Создание листа
struct leaf* Leaf_Create(char login[257], char pass[257], bool ring) {
    struct leaf* Leaf = new (struct leaf);
    strcpy_s(Leaf->login, login);
    strcpy_s(Leaf->pass, pass);
    Leaf->next = NULL;
    Leaf->ring = ring;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) Leaf->SessionID[i] = alphabet[GenerateRandom(0, 66)];
    Leaf->SessionID[256] = 0;
    return Leaf;
}


// Проверка на пустоту
bool DB_IsEmpty(struct tree* Tree) {
    return (Tree->root == NULL);
}


// Добавить лист (доп. функция к нижней)
void DB_AddUser_leaf(char login[257], char pass[257], struct leaf* Leaf, bool ring) {
    if (Leaf == NULL) Leaf = Leaf_Create(login, pass, ring);
    else DB_AddUser_leaf(login, pass, Leaf->next, ring);
}


// Добавить лист
void DB_AddUser(char login[257], char pass[257], struct tree* Tree, bool ring) {
    if (DB_IsEmpty(Tree)) Tree->root = Leaf_Create(login, pass, ring); else
        DB_AddUser_leaf(login, pass, Tree->root, ring);
}
```

Почему при добавлении листа (последняя функция) Tree-> root заполняется, а вот все сыновья Tree->root->next и т.д. нет (остаются NULL)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно присвоить указателю на указатель указатель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762251/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас во всем коде нет ни одного места, где бы указателям `->next` назначались ненулевые значения. Почему вас удивляет, что указатели `->next` остаются нулевыми?

У вас есть присваивание для `Tree->root` в функции `DB_AddUser`. Поэтому неудивительно, что `Tree->root` у вас получается ненулевой. А `->next` у вас нигде не присваивается вообще.

В функции `DB_AddUser_leaf` ветка `Leaf = Leaf_Create(login, pass, ring);` просто делает утечку памяти. `Leaf` наружу никак не передается и его значение просто теряется по завершении функции. То есть функция `DB_AddUser_leaf` ничего полезного не делает. Она только генерирует утечки памяти.

P.S. Вы уже, по-моему, в который раз задаете вопрос с разными вариациями одной и тот же ошибки ([Использование fopen_s в внешней функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979712/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-fopen-s-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)).

Comment: Спасибо
Сорри за однотипные вопросы, я, бывает, путаюсь при работе с указателями